# Dereferencing of smart pointer leading to coercion of type

Tags: rust

In module `db.rs`, I have  `struct Db` containing `entries` field of type `<Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Bytes>>>`. In the implementation of Db`(impl Db)`, i have a function `write`, which `insert or get` values from database.

```
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct Db {
    pub entries: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<String, Bytes>>>,
}
```

implementation of Db in `db.rs`

```
impl Db {
    pub fn new() -> Db {
        Db {
            entries: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
        }
    }
    pub fn write(self, arr: &[String]) -> Result<&str, &'static str> {
        let key = &arr[1];
        let value = &arr[2];
        let val = value.clone();
        let p = self
            .entries
            .lock()
            .unwrap()
            // .get(key);    //Coerced to: & Hashmap<String, Bytes>
            .insert(String::from(key), Bytes::from(val)); //Coerced to: &mut Hashmap<String, Bytes>
        match p {
            Some(p) => {
                Ok("r Ok")
            }, // if they key was already present
            None => Ok("Ok"), // if the key was not present
        }
    }
```

Here in `Write` function when i want to `get` or `set` data to DataBase, `.lock()` return the `Result<MutexGuard<HashMap<_, _>>>` but after `.unwrap()`, `MutexGuard` internally is `Coerced to` to  `&HashMap` and `&mut HashMap` for`.get()` and `.insert()` methods respectively. Since, `mutex` implements `deref` and `derefmut`, these coercion  are happening as a result of dereferencing of the smart pointers. but, How is this dereferencing getting triggered under the hood is what I am unclear about. Can anyone dive dipper into the inner functioning of `deref` in the code?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why there is a deref here even though you didn't explicitly write `*`?

Comment: Auto-dereferencing is a thing. Please edit the question if the linked questions do not clarify your concern.